# Nginx configuratie redirect http to https for only one domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

In the beginning of my Nginx .conf file I have added the following redirect:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name *.a-domain.nl;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;

    server_name *.a-domain.nl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/b-domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/b-domain.key;

    location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svgz|mp4|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|html|txt|htm)$ {
        root /var/www/html/mtcore/web;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name _;

    location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svgz|mp4|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|html|txt|htm)$ {
        root /var/www/html/mtcore/web;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

Only when I open in an browser the following domain www.b-domain.nl that is served on the same server, the Nginx also redirects it to https. I would expect that Nginx only redirects www.a-domain.nl?

Comment: What is your server configuration for `www.b-domain.nl`?

Comment: Hi Richard, I have added the complete config file. www.b-domain.nl should be triggered by server_name _; in the last server definition. But now the first definition is already redirecting it to https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first server block is the implicit default server for port 80, so it gets to process all `http` requests irrespective of server name. The third server block would only match the server name `_`, which is either illegal or unlikely.

To make another server block the default, use `default_server` option on the `listen` directive.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.